# Is there a way to set a pallet configuration using a function that lives on the outer node?

Tags: pallet, host-functions

I am aware that this should break consensus, as one may easily start a node with different params -> end up with a different wasm bytecode, and thus be on a different network. However, inspite of that, I would like to set a pallet configuration item, in this case a `Get<u32>`, such that the value instead of being hardcoded in the runtime file, is fed through, maybe a *host function*? If that's possible, how do I define such a *host function*?

In code:

Currently I have :

```rust
parameter_types! {
    pub const MyNumber: u32 = 10;
}
```

What I would like to have :

```rust
parameter_types! {
    pub const MyNumber: u32 = host_my_number();
}
```

The rationale being, for test purposes, I find it inconvenient having to recompile the entire runtime file after changing a single configuration parameter. I can easily instead pass a different argument to my node, and have my runtime configured by that way instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just define a struct yourself.

```rs
enum MyNumber {}
impl frame_support::traits::Get<u32> for MyNumber {
  fn get() -> u32 {
    host_my_number()
  }
}

impl Config for Runtime {
  type Number = MyNumber;
}
```

Comment: That's neat. Where do I put my `host_my_number()` though? :)

Comment: Anywhere that this code could access.

Comment: That's actually a part of my question. I do not know how to talk to host functions from the runtime as I assume I can't have a direct dependency on my `node` on my `runtime` crate. Am I wrong about that?

Comment: What's your use case? Maybe you just need to write a `fn random() -> u32 { Timestamp::now() as _ }` here.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question : I want to be able to make a host function, that keeps track of a number, either fed through the CLI or maybe use randomness, and from there I want to call that function in my runtime. How can I do that? I am not asking for the entire code logic, just how do I call any outer node function from my wasm runtime?

Comment: For host function, you can check https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2713/how-might-we-introduce-a-new-host-function-into-the-polkadot-ecosystem.